# MkDir Failed creating directory PHP

Tags: php, mkdir

I am trying to create a directory using PHP this works:

```
<?php
$uid = "user_615";
$thisdir = getcwd(); 

if(mkdir($thisdir ."/userpics/" . $uid , 0777)) 
{ 
   echo "Directory has been created successfully..."; 
} 
else 
{ 
   echo "Failed to create directory..."; 
} 
?>
```

but this does not work

```
<?php
session_start();
$uid = $_SESSION['username'];
$thisdir = getcwd(); 

if(mkdir($thisdir ."/userpics/" . $uid , 0777)) 
{ 
   echo "Directory has been created successfully..."; 
} 
else 
{ 
   echo "Failed to create directory..."; 
} 
?>
```

Yes the session variable is populated with the exact same thing as above 'user_615' so why would the second one be failing?

**EDIT:**

So I took the suggestion of @stefgosselin and re-designed the code to be

```
<?php
session_start();
$uid = $_SESSION['username'];
$thisdir = getcwd() . "/userpics" . $uid; 

if(mkdir($thisdir , 0777)) 
{ 
   echo "Directory has been created successfully..."; 
} 
else 
{ 
   echo "Failed to create directory..."; 
   echo "Your thisdir Variable is:'" . $thisdir . "'" ;
} 
?>
```

And the output is

> Failed to create directory...Your thisdir Variable is:'/unified/b/bis/www.mysite.com/jou/userpics/user_615

Any other ideas on what would cause the a Session variable not to be able to used in creating a directory?

Comment: I *think* what stefgosselin is trying to say is you should store the entire path in a variable and check it's value as a debugging method. Are you *suuuure* the session data is correct? There's no other explanation I can think of.

Comment: Yeah. That was the simple point I was trying to make. Sorry for my bad english. I have to read 3 times before posting and even then the wording is funny sometimes. :o/

Comment: "Your thisdir Variable is:'/unified/b/bis/www.mysite.com/jou/userpics'" Doesn't seem to be a uid on the end there like there should be.

Comment: I didn't copy the whole line somehow but yes the name showed up sorry for the mistake.

Comment: @atrljoe and you are 100% sure that is a valid path? Oh, if the directory exists, I believe mkdir would also fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a small tip, I would simply put all of `$thisdir` in a variable and check if the output of that adds up to the result you are expecting.

IE: Having  `$thisdir ."/userpics/" . $uid` defined in a variable would give you the possibility to easily output and  validate the argument value you are passing to `mkdir`.

Edit: Adjusted minor phrasing for better english translation.  Sorry above wasn't clear, Wesley understood the simple point I was clumsily trying to make.

Comment: I can't make any sense of this answer, what is `<englobing>` and what are you saying?

Comment: My thoughts exactly. However, I've seen @stef gosselin's answers before and they are typically good, so I am reserving judgment.

Comment: @Wesley Thanks guys. I edited the post I had made. And to be fair, I did say all along it was a *small tip*. If I was to debug that code, the first thing I would do is what I wrote in my answer.

Comment: The part I'm having difficulty believing is "Yes the session variable is populated with the exact same thing as above 'user_615'". That's the only difference between the two code blocks.