# PHP mkdir doesn't make new directories

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make a new directory to handle profile pictures, but every time I upload the image, nothing happens as in the new directory is not created and there are no errors whatsoever. I already checked the Apache error log, but didn't notice any error pertaining to my recent code...

Here's a sample of my code

```
    //profile image upload script
    if (isset($_FILES['profile_pics'])) {
        if (((@$_FILES["profile_pics"] ["type"] == "image/jpeg" || (@$_FILES["profile_pics"] ["type"] == "image/png") || (@$_FILES["profile_pics"] ["type"] == "image/gif")) && (@$_FILES["profile_pics"] ["size"] < 1048576)) ) // LESS THAN ONE MEGABYTE

        {
            $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
            $rand_dir_name = substr(str_shuffle($chars), 0, 15);
            mkdir("userdata/profile_pics/$rand_dir_name");




        else {

        }
```

}
        }

Comment: Please add error reporting at the top of your file(s): `<?php
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ?>` And tell us the errors. Also check the permissions of the dir that you are allowed to create new sub dir's

Comment: make sure the directory in which you are creating new directories has proper permissions

Comment: May be helpful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101840/mkdir-failed-creating-directory-php?rq=1
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13908722/php-unable-to-create-a-directory-with-mkdir?rq=1

Comment: Use an absolute path, and make sure the directory has write permissions, 0775 should do it in most cases

Comment: done any basic debugging, like checking mkdir()'s return value? plus. don't use `@`. it's the coding equivalent of stuffing your fingers in your ears and going "lalalalalala can't hear you"

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple errors in your PHP, are you sure you did not see any FATAL errors in your apache logs?

- Your `if` query does not close properly
- Your `else` statement is missing a braket
- You're suppressing any errors with `@` - remove them!
- Use an absolute path instead of relative path to avoid errors in where you're creating the directory

Here's an example of how it should look:

```
// array of valid image types
$valid = array( 'image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif' );

if (isset($_FILES['profile_pics'])) {

    // if the file type is in the valid array and the size is less than 1MB
    if ( in_array($_FILES['profile_pics']['type'], $valid)
         && ($_FILES["profile_pics"]["size"] < 1048576) )
    {
        $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
        $rand_dir_name = substr(str_shuffle($chars), 0, 15);
        mkdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/userdata/profile_pics/$rand_dir_name");

    } else {
        print( 'too big or not an image.' );
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

You should also check the `mkdir` response.. like this:

```
    $ok = mkdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/userdata/profile_pics/$rand_dir_name");

    if( !$ok )
    {
        print('error creating directory, check your permissions');
    } else {
        print('created directory successfully!');
    }
```

Comment: You're also missing parentheses for `if ( in_array($_FILES['profile_pics']['type'], $valid)`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Looks ok to me... if statement is on two lines to make it easier for the OP to read.. maybe that's the confusion ( note the `&&` )

Comment: Ok, my mistake Danny. You're right about the `&&` - Just the way it was entered in my IDE.

Comment: No worries Fred, do you think I've made it less readable like this? if so, i'll put it all on one line

Comment: I'd leave it, see what the OP says. When everything's accounted for, then sure, that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add permission.

mkdir("/path/", 0755);